# Give paid Android app for free to physical product customers?

Tags: android, google-play

We are selling a physical product, and have created an Android app to interface with it over bluetooth.

We would like to release this app on the Google Play store as a paid app, to discourage competitors from using it with similar compatible products.

But the plan is to provide our customers with a code to download the app for free through email.

But the Google Play promo codes seem to be limited to 500 per quarter, and we need more than this. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Dont make your product compatible.

Comment: Easier said than done

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

Create your own in-app code checking (or login) mechanism, this will require you to handle the whole process from your side and you will need backend to create codes and verify them.

**Option 2**

publish a [Private app](https://support.google.com/googleplay/work/answer/6145139#zippy=%2Cregister-as-a-developer%2Callow-rd-party-developer-publishing%2Cpublish-to-your-own-organization) via Google Play console, you will be able to give access to users like closed testing app.